Policy: The Rule of Cool answer type
This is a follow-up from this question: Here
Initially I proposed this as a Close reason - but after some good commentary, especially JBHs point that whilst a Rule of Cool closure reason could be valid, it is perhaps a step too far - I have decided to create this Meta Post to formally define a Rule of Cool answer as a valid non-answer.
This is in the same spirit of the formalization of the Frame Challenge
What is a Rule of Cool Answer?

A Rule of Cool answer is one that makes the case to a World Builder that in attempting to rationalize a particular idea or element, they are taking away from the mystery of the unknown, whereby the person interacting with the world (viewer, reader, gamer etc.) fills it with their imagination.

Rule of Cool has its genesis in DnD - whereby when there is a dispute about rules or the interpretation of the rules, DMs are encouraged to seek solutions that make the game more fun, more playable - or... More cool.
Examples include:

The force in the original Star Wars Trilogy
Sharknado
Space Battleship Yamato
Mecha being completely impractical due to ground pressure
Revolvers being one-shot hand cannons, whereas a semi-auto pistol (firing the same calibre projectile) are not

Often, Rule of Cool will be invoked where someone has a seemingly absurd or contradictory idea, that they are seeking to rationally justify - and yet when a 3rd party looks at it, they are willing to suspend disbelief, because the idea is inherently... Cool.
To Codify this - a Rule of Cool answer should contain 3 key parts:
Rule of Cool is in effect (or similar) - just like most people who post Frame Challenge at the start of a Frame Challenge answer, stating that your are invoking Rule of Cool (so as to not have it deleted as a non-answer) is good Netiquette.
Why you think Rule of Cool applies
This section could be as simple as:

T-Rex Cavalry? That is awesome, I am in.

Or it could be a long in-depth discussion of similar ideas in other media whereby attempts to justify or rationalize a particular plot element has not enhanced the world building.
My Go-To example here is The Force in the original Trilogy - which was quasi-mystical magic, to the Prequel Trilogy, whereby it is a product of Midiclorians and a persons strength in the Force is determined by the concentration of these. Me, personally, I think Star Wars lost something special about the Force when it attempted to give it a coherent explanation.
This is not to say my opinion is the be-all and end-all and I understand that other people did enjoy the Midiclorian explanation.
However, regardless of the length or detail, The answer should have an explanation as to why a potential reader would suspend disbelief over such an idea.
Why further justification is detrimental to the world
This is the final key part of a Rule of Cool answer - that the more the world builder attempts to justify and rationalize a concept, the more it is going to detract from the World.
I mentioned above Mecha being totally impractical due to ground pressure, this is a great example - The more someone tries to justify why their Mecha could totally work, the more it draws attention to the inherent problems of such an idea and the more it works to undermine the suspension of disbelief of the reader, viewer, gamer etc.
I am willing to ignore certain facts about Mecha - because 100 ft tall fighting robots are awesome. Pacific Rim the movie (great movie btw.) has a number of completely ridiculous premises... And yet - I forgive every single one of them because Giant Robots fighting Giant Monsters tickles my imagination.
Same with the Marvel Movies - seeing Iron Man go from flying at supposedly supersonic speeds to a dead stop in a fraction of a second should result in Robert Downey Jr being turned into a Physics lesson a la the Byford Dolphin decompression accident - but again, Iron Man is cool, his suit is cool and I am looking the other way. If the Movie tried to go into detail about how the suit had inertial dampers and this and that and the other - it would take away from the World Building of the character and it would draw the viewers attention to the fact that it wouldn't work.
A valid Rule of Cool answer Must contain both parts. The first part can be rather brief, but it must be supported by the latter part - it is not enough to say something is cool and you (as a potential reader) are invested, you must also outline why trying to push for ultra-realism or justification for their idea runs counter to the World Building process or the goals that they seek to achieve
A common theme, especially after popular hard-science series, is that everything must be grounded in reality or justified. This is not to say that there is not a time and place for realism and justifcations (otherwise we as a community would not exist) - but to encourage the asker to consider where and when to draw the line for a World Building project, so as to allow the space to be filled with the imagination of the reader or viewer.
If the community believes this is a good idea, then after the prerequisite number of up-votes, we can add this to the Wiki as another acceptable non-answer.

@elemtilas - I will tidy up and address some of those points.

@elemtilas - I have removed potential, and clarified on your point 2 - so that would not be a full answer, it needs the second part - why it is detrimental to WB Process, I have added a couple of paragraphs to reference JBHs point(s) - might tweak it a bit more later.

Could redirect them to story-teller's corner..... The remit there is a bit vague at present, perhaps needs formalizing (a little, at least).

@Escapeddentalpatient. The story tellers corner chat room should be where people go to ask questions that are too story-based. It shouldn't become the catch-all for all questions (which is what The Factory Floor was supposed to be... then it died... and the story tellers corner has the same risk). Besides, this is an answer type that should explain the worldbuilding process that rationalizes why no additional details should be introduced - which I doubt any chat room would ever produce without moderation.

We're almost there, folks! +8 needs to become +10 to officially make this a policy. If you're having difficulties with the idea, post an answer explaining it so we can get everything out in the open.

You've had my upvote, I was just advertising to stop the corner dying. (Technically spam, but not in spirit).

@Escapeddentalpatient. I wish there was an easier way to do it. Burying things in the Help Center is two shades better than dark. Chat never seems to have been very important to SE.

I need 2 more votes..

It's a shame I can't bounty a meta question. I'm arrogantly and egocentrically declaring this a raging success! Let's start using it and see where it takes us. We'll know in the first half-dozen answers whether or not this needs refinement. (And while I'm at it... are 160 of the 186 views browser bots? ...or maybe SE staff?)

@JBH - those are probably me refreshing the question to see if there has been any more movement on it :D

This is awesome. I'm in!
I would like to underscore your third requirement, which I believe is the most important of the three. What makes the Rule of Cool answer type valuable is that it must be a worldbuilding-process answer that helps both the OP and future worldbuilders to understand with specific examples when to draw the line between chasing the realism rabbit and depending on imagination to do its job.
In this regard, the answer begins to bridge a long-standing problem on this Stack: storybuilding questions. We love 'em, and they're prohibited. The reason they're prohibited is that it's fundamentally impossible to have a single objectively correct answer.
The Rule of Cool answer type helps people see the necessary wall between worldbuilding and storybuilding and gives them insight into when to build the world and when to write the story.
To that end it should be noted that the justification must be non-trivial. It must be more than, "I like this idea, you really don't need more!" It must educate, not simply admire.

+1 for tying this in with worldbuilding process!

Towards a First Answer

I've posted a RoC answer to this question. I believe I got both the requisite bits in! I concur with the others: we should have formally considered this sooner! I know we've been kind of dancing around this issue on many occasions, usually in comments, mostly in response to the over-scientification / overjustification of many questions we get.

Honestly not sure why we didn’t do this earlier.
I’ve answered several times (here, here, here, here, here… the list goes on) basically saying “whatever, man, if you need it for the story, just do it.” Trying to rationalize things that can’t be rationalized (or, in this case, shouldn’t be) seems like something that’s decently common, for a type of post whose instances all pretty much have the same answer. Having a specific allowed non-answer for these cases seems right.
Whether those posts in particular fit exactly what this is talking about is potentially up for debate (I haven’t been around nearly as long as JBH or DemonLord but I’ve got a semi-decent grasp on how this stuff works), but this is a perfect idea, and it’s a great way to put a label on something that ends up happening rather frequently here. In the OP’s answer, simply extend “mystery of the unknown” to “scientific impossibilities”, “fantastical elements”, etc. and we’ve got pretty much use case for a RoC non-answer I’ve yet seen in my 10 months.
